# Travelling for 3 months hence want to give up rental contract

Tags: germany, rental

I am planning to give up my rental contract as I wish to go on a long vacation to my home country. Currently I am residing in Berlin Germany, so my query is:

1. Is it okay for us not to have any registered address for around 3 months?
2. Is it okay to use temporary mail address (e.g.  mailboxde.com) to receive mails from government agencies like Auslander Behorde or to Standesamt?

Or is it possible to find temporary address where you just want to register yourself (anmeldung) but not stay and you pay fraction of the rent for this service?

Comment: I'll move this question for you to our sistersite expatriates as they are more familiar with the rules for registration in Germany.

Comment: Which citizenship(s) do you have? Do you need a visa to live/work/study in Germany, and if so which kind of visa do you have?

Answer (score 2):

For your situation:

- you must deregister when you move out, [§ 17 ⑵ BMG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html#p0184)

  - and register your new residence after your return, [§ 17 ⑴ BMG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html#p0184)
- absence outside of Germany up to 6 months has no effect on your residence permit (if you require one), [§ 51 ⑴ № 7 AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1050)

  - if you’ll move to a *different* address, inform the Immigration office of your new address after your return (→ amendment of residence title card)

You can have your post sent on to any address (up to 6 months), but you cannot register that address as your residence.

However, *certain* mailings, such as a court summons, require a *ladungsfähige* *Anschrift*, i.e. an address where you *do* regularly stay, specifically a friend’s home or POB will not be sufficient.
This is one reason why you should deregister, because otherwise such a notice would be considered as served.

Such an application must be made for each postal service, such as Deutsche Post.